# Is there a way to close the Applozic Web Client?

Tags: applozic

Is there a way to close the [Applozic Web Client](https://www.applozic.com/docs/web-chat-plugin.html), e.g. when a user logs out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$applozic("#mck-sidebox").mckModal('hide');
$applozic.fn.applozic('logout');
```

Comment: The first line did not close the launcher (i.e. the floating circle), but this did: `$applozic("#mck-sidebox-launcher").hide()`.  It would be nice to have an API call to shut everything down.

Comment: thanks @mikebridge for the suggestion, we will add that.